# Contar filas de textarea en input

Tags: php, html, script

Estoy tratando de contar las filas de un text área e insertándolas en un input, pero tengo el problema que cuando el campo del textarea esta vació me esta marcando "2" y debería ser "1", no se donde esta el problema, ya que no tengo espacio, ni saltos de linea entre el pretextara, ni en código ni en ejecución.

**Código.**

```
<div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <label>Numero de racks</label>
    <input id="lines">
    <textarea id="ta" class="form-control" name="racksI"></textarea>
</div>
```

**Script.**

```
var calculateContentHeight = function( ta, scanAmount ) {
    var origHeight = ta.style.height,
        height = ta.offsetHeight,
        scrollHeight = ta.scrollHeight,
        overflow = ta.style.overflow;
    /// only bother if the ta is bigger than content
    if ( height >= scrollHeight ) {
        /// check that our browser supports changing dimension
        /// calculations mid-way through a function call...
        ta.style.height = (height + scanAmount) + 'px';
        /// because the scrollbar can cause calculation problems
        ta.style.overflow = 'hidden';
        /// by checking that scrollHeight has updated
        if ( scrollHeight < ta.scrollHeight ) {
            /// now try and scan the ta's height downwards
            /// until scrollHeight becomes larger than height
            while (ta.offsetHeight >= ta.scrollHeight) {
                ta.style.height = (height -= scanAmount)+'px';
            }
            /// be more specific to get the exact height
            while (ta.offsetHeight < ta.scrollHeight) {
                ta.style.height = (height++)+'px';
            }
            /// reset the ta back to it's original height
            ta.style.height = origHeight;
            /// put the overflow back
            ta.style.overflow = overflow;
            return height;
        }
    } else {
        return scrollHeight;
    }
}

var calculateHeight = function() {
    var ta = document.getElementById("ta"),
        style = (window.getComputedStyle) ?
            window.getComputedStyle(ta) : ta.currentStyle,
        
        // This will get the line-height only if it is set in the css,
        // otherwise it's "normal"
        taLineHeight = parseInt(style.lineHeight, 10),
        // Get the scroll height of the textarea
        taHeight = calculateContentHeight(ta, taLineHeight),
        // calculate the number of lines
        numberOfLines = Math.ceil(taHeight / taLineHeight);

    document.getElementById("lines").value = numberOfLines;
};

calculateHeight();
if (ta.addEventListener) {
    ta.addEventListener("mouseup", calculateHeight, false);
    ta.addEventListener("keyup", calculateHeight, false);
} else if (ta.attachEvent) { // IE
    ta.attachEvent("onmouseup", calculateHeight);
    ta.attachEvent("onkeyup", calculateHeight);
}
```

**Resultado.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al dar los enter si me va aumentando el input, pero no logro obtener el problema que solo al cargar cuando esta vació sale el input en 2, encontré ese script, pero quiero lograr eso, si alguien tiene otro podría ayudarme o guiar.

Comment: Si al final vas a delimitar las filas por el enter, por que no tomas el valor de el textbox y le haces un split por ```\n```

Answer (score 0):

**Con el siguiente script solucione el problema.**

```
function valida(){
    var lineas=1; //contador de líneas
    var caract=0;
    var contadorbucle=-1;
    var contadorpalabra= -1;
    var contadortotal =-1;
    var texto = document.form1.textarea.value;
    
    while (contadorbucle < document.form1.textarea.value.length){
        contadorbucle = contadorbucle + 1;
        contadorpalabra=contadorpalabra+1;      
        //alert ('espacio!!');
        if (texto.charAt(contadorbucle)==' '){
            contadorpalabra=-1;
        }
        contadortotal=contadortotal + 1;
        if (texto.charAt(contadorbucle)=='\n'){
            lineas=lineas+1;
            contadorpalabra=-1;
            contadortotal=-1;
        }
        if (contadorpalabra > 0 && contadortotal==document.form1.textarea.cols){
        contadortotal=contadorpalabra;
        lineas=lineas+1;
        }
        
        if (contadortotal==document.form1.textarea.cols){
            lineas=lineas+1;
            contadorpalabra=0;
            contadortotal=0;
        }
        
        
    } 
    document.form1.lineas.value = lineas;
}
```

Y en el siguiente input me cambia el valor del numero de filas.

```
<input name="racksI" type="hidden" id="lineas" class="form-control">
```

Comment: Hola y por que no consideraste usar jquery?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035910/how-to-get-the-number-of-lines-in-a-textarea/2036424